# how to configure a database drivers in java automatically

Tags: java, jdbc, configuration, installation, odbc

I have created a java desktop application where I use MS Access as back end. I configured the ODBC drivers manually by clicking on control panel>administrative tools>ODBC Data sources and by selecting the drivers and database. It's working fine as I run it on Netbeans IDE

I am using Install Creator to make an .exe file. if I do so how and where should I place the database inside the installer and how to configure the ODBC drivers automatically when I install the software in another system.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a DSN (Data Source Name) to use an ODBC Driver. You can use a) FILEDSN or b) DSN-less connections. File DSNs are where you put the attribute and value pairs which describe the database connection in a file and pass FILEDSN=c:\path_to_file in SQLDriverConnect. DSN-less connections are where you pass all the attribute/value pairs required to SQLDriverConnect and it must contain a DRIVER={whatever the driver is called}.